# What is the minimum permission needed by user to be able to share files/folders/manage permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

1. What is the minimum permission that a user needs to:

- Share files/folders
- Share document library
- Share site

2. Can user share only files/folders/doc library that was owned by them or can they share it even if they don't own it?

Answer (score 0):

1.Share Files/Folders:
To share individual files or folders, a user typically requires at least “Read” permissions to the library where those files or folders reside.

2.Share Document Library:
Sharing an entire document library involves a bit more flexibility.
By default, document libraries inherit permissions from the site they belong to. This means that if a user has permissions to the site, they can share the entire library.

3.Share Site:
Sharing a site (or site collection) is typically done by users with “Full Control” or “Site Owner” permissions.

4.Users can share files/folders/document libraries to which they have permissions

Comment: My visitors cannot share. So your answer that users with read permission can share doesn't look right